# How can I write my SQL query in LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table that looks like this.  The query needs to return the last date entry for each location. How would I write this in SQL and LINQ?

```
Id  Location        Salary  Date
1   Los Angeles     $1500   Jan-05-1999 
2   San Diego       $250    Jan-07-1999 
3   Los Angeles     $300    Jan-08-1999
4   Boston          $700    Jan-08-1999
5   Los Angeles     $300    Jan-08-1999
```

The result would be:

```
2   San Diego       $250    Jan-07-1999
4   Boston          $700    Jan-08-1999
5   Los Angeles     $300    Jan-08-1999
```

Comment: Did you also want the $ amount in your results?

Comment: yes, it would just be a nvarchar field

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind I'm pretty new to link, and I don't think this is the best way:

```
var collection = from d in <TABLE> select d;
collection = collection.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Last());
```

Basically just group on the date and take the last one. I couldn't think of a good way to do this in the LINQ command, so I just selected all the rows - anyone know to combine these lines?

Comment: Yes, you can simply replace collection with TABLE in line 2.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates included time, then you could:

```
var locations = 
   from l in mycontext.Locations
   where l.Date = mycontext.Locations
         .Where(l2=>l.Location == l2.Location)
         .Max(l2.Date)
   select l;
```

Alternatively, assuming ID is an identity and the records are inserted in the table when they occurred(your example seems to hint so), you can do:

```
var locations = 
   from l in mycontext.Locations
   where l.ID = mycontext.Locations
         .Where(l2=>l.Location == l2.Location)
         .Max(l2.ID)
   select l;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT location, max(date)

FROM yourtable

GROUP BY location
```

EDIT: I didn't see the results being asked for or not sure if it was there originally:

```
SELECT yourtable.id, yourtable.location, yourtable.salary, yourtable.date
FROM yourtable INNER JOIN
  (SELECT yourtable.location, MAX(yourtable.date) as thedate
   FROM yourtable
   GROUP BY yourtable.location) AS MYRESULT 
   on MYRESULT.thedate = yourtable.date  
      AND MYRESULT.location = yourtable.location
```

Haven't tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

@Bobby Shaftoe

I believe that he was looking for the latest entry rather than the latest date for every location. If my assumption is correct, it would be more like

```
SELECT max(ID),location,date
FROM tablename
GROUP BY location
```

Comment: Well, he said date entry. However, if his data is consistent, it looks like it would be the same thing, perhaps. But I stick with what I have based on the question was written, you might be right though.

Comment: Oh, and there is a mistake in this one. The DB will complain that "date" is not in group by clause or in an aggregate function.

Comment: He has the result he expects here - it's the full row. Not sure if it was there originally though.

Answer (score 0):

To get the whole row with the max date for each location, I think the SQL is:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Location, t1.Salary, t1.Date
FROM YourTable t1, 
    (SELECT Location, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Location) t2
WHERE t1.Location = t2.Location
AND t1.Date = t2.MaxDate
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: how would you write this in LINQ?

Comment: Yeah, great question :) The short answer is I don't know Linq well enough.
I know linq tends to mirror sql somewhat, but I don't know the exact syntax (if there is one) for grouping and joining.
You may have to follow Steve Willard's example - select everything and pare it down using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not so straight forward if I read this question correctly. Because Los Angeles has 2 entries on the Max date there appears to be a further rule that in that situation the max ID should be selected.

In that case the SQL becomes a little more complex, 2 groupings are required....

```
select id, location, salary, date from 
locations where id in
(select  max(id) as MaxID
from locations where date in (
Select Max(Date) as MaxDate from Locations group by Location)
Group by location)
```

The corresponding Linq query, would also require 2 groupings...

```
  var qry = from a in locations
            group a by a.Location into grp
            from b in grp
            where b.Date == grp.Max(o => o.Date)
            group b by b.Location into grp2
            from c in grp2
            where c.ID == grp2.Max(obj => obj.ID)
            orderby c.ID
            select c;
```